# Is the destructor the only thing ever called on the RHS of a move ctor/assignment?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

My search-fu is good, but this is a difficult one to phrase correctly to find the answer. Basically, after a move ctor/assignment is invoked, is it guaranteed that the only thing that will ever be called on the RHS will be the destructor?

The reason I ask is that I have various things that (for sanity's sake) cannot be in an invalid state. But, far and away the most efficient move scheme would be to swap some stuff into them that the dtor can accept but nothing else could. Else, I have to allocate actual data, no matter how trivial, to keep the RHS in a valid state.

If the dtor is the only thing that will ever get called, then I can get maximum efficiency.

Comment: Relevant: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/code/object-relocation-in-terms-of-move-plus-destroy-draft-7.html

Answer (score 1):

> is it guaranteed that the only thing that will ever be called on the RHS will be the destructor?

No. It is well-formed to call member functions of a moved from object.  The standard doesn't guarantee that a programmer won't do that.

As the implementor of a class, you can decide that some member functions must not be called on a moved from object, and thus can avoid for example allocating memory. Or, you can decide to not have such requirement. In general, having preconditions can allow more efficient implementation, while not having preconditions makes the class easier to use.

As the user of a class, you are responsible for following the preconditions of the member functions that you call (or member access). If a precondition of a function is that class is not in a moved from state, then don't break that precondition.

As a general rule, it's probably a good design to allow assignment operator to be called on a moved from object. That's what all (assignable) standard library classes do.

---

In short: There is no such guarantee by the standard, but you can impose such requirement on the user of the class. Just make sure it is well documented.

Comment: OK, I was thinking only about compiler generated moves, which I thought was only done on temporaries. My own actual move ctors/assignments that force moves on their contents I will trust not to do anything wrong. In the rare cases where something is just forced to move in the general course of events, I'm willing to deal with being caught by assertions. But, in the case of compiler generated automatic ones, where it's a temp that never is accessible otherwise, is it always just going to be destroyed and that's it?

Comment: If the object is used in a standard container (e.g. `std::vector<Foo>`) then there's no guarantee of `std::vector` observing whichever conditions the author imposes ,  so this approach is setting a difficult and bug-prone task for the user

Comment: @M.M If the type is stored in a standard container, then the type must adhere to the requirements of the container and the operations used. If the container requires the type to be Assignable, then the type must be Assignable unconditionally.

Comment: I don't use the STL. I have my own (very large, million lines of code) code base, which includes everything from built tools, to virtual kernel, to standard libraries, all the way up to a very powerful automation system called CQC. So I don't have to worry about anyone's code but mine. So that might make my situation a bit different than usual.

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing magic about moving from an object. After a move the object is still valid and if it’s not a temporary your code can call member functions on it and pass it to functions.

Just like any other object, and this is really the point of the question, the **compiler** won’t do anything to an object other than destroy it at the end of its lifetime. For a temporary object, that’s the end of the full statement that creates the object. For a named object, that’s the end of the scope in which the object is created.